# Как выделить все checkBox в listView на android

Tags: java, android, listview

Есть `listView` и `adapter` добавленный к `listView`. В конструктор `adapter` передается `context` и `ArrayList` с данными. Как выделить все `checkBox` в `listView` используя одну кнопку(SelectAll) расположенную на том-же `activity`?

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо

1. завести в адаптере список `boolean` значений равный длине списка данных
2. При нажатии на кнопку каждому элементу этого списка в адаптере присвоить `true`
3. и вызываем над адаптером метод `notifyDataSetChanged()` коий вызовет перерисовку всех элементов `listView`
4. в `getView()` методе адаптера надо проверять условие `if(listOfBooleans.get(position) == true)`
5. Если входим в условие - "чекаем" `checkBox`, иначе снимаем с него выбор.

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение:

```
public View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
    try {
        final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

        if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition) {
            //This may occure using Android Monkey, else will work otherwise
            return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
        } else {
            final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
            return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Поясните что конкретно этот код делает. Похоже, что он возвращает View элемента по позиции. но зачем?...