# ListView Adapter не запоминает состояние Checkbox-ов

Tags: android, listview, adapter

У меня есть список с чекбоксом, по дефолту все элементы `false`. При клике по чекбоксу у элемента должно становиться `true` и изменить этот параметр в объекте, в списке. Подозреваю, что проблема с методоми `setTag()` и `getTag()`.
При клике объект изменяется, даже записывается, но когда я перезайду в эту категорию, все равно подтягиваются первые данные.
Вопрос - почему подтягиваются старые данные, а не модифицированные?

Вот весь код ViewAdapter:

```
public class NewItemListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NewShop> {
private OnPlusButtonClickListenner listenner;
private ArrayList<NewShop> listItems;
private DataFactory dataFactory = new DataFactory();
private NewFavoriteFactory favoriteFactory;

public NewItemListViewAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<NewShop> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    favoriteFactory = new NewFavoriteFactory(context);
    listItems = dataFactory.getListShop(Type.Mountain);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_item_list, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Bitmap bitmapFon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.white_fon);
    Bitmap bitmapIconShop = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), getItem(position).getIconShop());
    holder.icon.setImageBitmap(MyBitMap.getBitmapForCategory(bitmapFon, bitmapIconShop));
    holder.icon.setTag(position);
    holder.icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
            getItem(pos);

            if (listenner != null) {
                listenner.onPlusClick(listItems.get(position).getUrlShop());
            }
        }
    });

    holder.favoriteShop.setChecked(getItem(position).getFavoriteShop());
    holder.favoriteShop.setTag(position);
    holder.favoriteShop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
            boolean checked = ((CompoundButton) v).isChecked();
            getItem(pos).setFavoriteShop(checked);
            // real save
            String item = new Gson().toJson(getItem(pos).getId());
            if (checked) {
                Log.d(StringVariables.TEST, "save");
                PrefUtil.save(getContext(), item);
            } else {
                Log.d(StringVariables.TEST, "remove");
                PrefUtil.remove(getContext(), item);
            }
        }
    });


    holder.name.setText(getItem(position).getNameShop());
    holder.name.setTag(position);
    holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
            getItem(pos);

            if (listenner != null) {
                listenner.onPlusClick(listItems.get(position).getUrlShop());
            }
        }
    });

    convertView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener(position));

    return convertView;
}

public void setOnPlusClickListenner(OnPlusButtonClickListenner listenner) {
    this.listenner = listenner;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    private ImageView icon;
    private TextView name;
    private CheckBox favoriteShop;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iconShop);
        name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nameShop);
        favoriteShop = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxFavorite);
    }
 }
}
```

Данные хранятся в таком виде:

```
ArrayList<NewShop> listBike = new ArrayList<>();

    listBike.add(new NewShop(1, R.drawable.icon_universal, "Velomarket", "http://velomarket.org.ua/", false));
    listBike.add(new NewShop(2, R.drawable.icon_extrim_style, "Екстрем Стайл", "http://extremstyle.ua/", false));
```

Answer (score 1):

почитайте мой ответ [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/477016/17609). Кратко: вам не нужны set/getTag. Вам нужно хранить позиции чекнутых элементов. В getView проверять чекнут ли элемент и чекать его/очищать. При нажатии надо вызывать метод перерисовки элементов адаптера.